# Полоска на AutoParalaxBackGround

Tags: andengine

Вопрос в чем: есть картинка, которая двигается на заднем фоне, но почему-то на стыке изображений получается полоска небольшая, примерно в 1px, как от нее избавиться?

Answer (score 1):

У меня решилось эта проблема предварительной загрузкой фоновой текстуры со смещением по оси X! Точно объяснить как это работает я не могу, но у меня данную  проблему этот способ решил!

```
 BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameBKTexture, context, "bk_game.jpg", 0, 0);
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameBKTexture, context, "bk_game.jpg", 6, 0);
        gameBK = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameBKTexture, context, "bk_game.jpg", 3, 0);
```